# Should be USB stick drives be hot to touch when idle?

Tags: usb, drive

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and it was my first main foray into Linux (I had 18.04 for one week prior to upgrading).

I connect two SanDisk USB stick drives to my Dell laptop but they are used infrequently, however they are always hot to touch when the laptop is on. Is that normal? If that is normal, will that level of heat degrade them in anyway?

Also, where there is heat there is power, so it will obviously be reducing battery life too. Is there anyway of 'turning' them off until I need them (without removing them, smart ars*s)?

Comment: No, a USB flash drives should not be hot, there are no moving parts in there. do they smell at all? I think that they might be shorting out!!

Comment: I have noticed this problem too, and it is getting more common with newer USB sticks, probably because they are faster than before. -- *I think the expected life-time is reduced at high temperature*, and they are also wasting energy.

Comment: They do not smell at all and this has been the case for a couple of months now and both drives still work fine.

Comment: ok, I don't use USB drives that much.

Comment: @Nath heat from electronic components like a flash drive or SSD isn't caused by moving parts, it's caused by electricity passing thru the parts. If the drive has been writing constantly for a long time, it can warm up.  Generally PCB and silicon can often get up to 100C before any damage is done. I'm assuming the flash drive is way way below that.

Comment: @norfolk_uk dose it burn?

Comment: Should be able to unmount(turn off) them by 'files' or other programs.  Would worry if they are too hot to hold in hand, remove if you are not nearby for a time.

Comment: They're def not burning and the bits that get hot are actually the thin stainless steel 'jacket' set into the main plastic frame. Yes they are not 100C - I can keep my finger on them forever but they're still warm enough. Why is electricity flowing through them when they are not even being accessed. Even if I 'eject' them for removal but leave them in the laptop they still stay so warm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you plug in any USB device, the first thing that happens ("first" is enforced by plug design), is that the computer supplies power (`+5V`  `GND`) to the USB device.

The USB device runs a tiny computer to communicate with the computer.

The first message sent is "I am a disk/mouse/keyboard/NIC/...", and here's how we'll communicate.

Then, the tiny computer devotes its attention to behaving like a "disk/mouse/keyboard/NIC/..." and communicating with the host computer via the appropriate USB protocol.

In your case, it's pretending to be a disk, ready to accept "disk" commands via USB.

Running the tiny cpu takes power, and dissipates heat (see "Laws of Thermodynamics").

Is it excessive power usage? Will the USB device frogboil itself?

Probably not, but YMMV.

Power dissipation is a concept known to Electrical Engineers and Product Designers.